# Exclude custom post type from search by custom field value?

Tags: custom-field, search

I've been unable to find anything on how to do this, or if it's even possible.

What I want to do is not display results of search in custom post type "resources" on which "resource_usertype" (key) is not "Public" or "Students" or "Alumni" (values).

Or maybe a better way to say it is to only display search results in which values of "resource_usertype" are "Public", "Students", or "Alumni".

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a hook for `pre_get_posts` filter, in which you can set what you need. Pay attention that you should change only search query, so you have to check if `is_search()` method returns true. The hook should look like this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse8170_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse8170_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'resources' ) );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => 'resource_usertype',
                'value' => array('Public', 'Students', 'Alumni'),
                'compare' => 'IN',
            )
        ) );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Eugene - this looks like it would work, but it actually excludes all results on all post types and pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible!

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'resources',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'resource_usertype',
           'value' => array('Public', 'Students', 'Alumni'),
           'compare' => 'IN',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: This is a query for listings, isn't it?. Specifically trying to exclude from search results.