# How to control WordPress Search Behavior?

Tags: search, design

I'm developing a website using WordPress and I need to make a totally customized theme. Everything seem to work well until I found something wrong at search result which doesn't match with customer requirements. I have no experience with PHP and WordPress. So let me ask two questions.

1. How can I validate the WordPress Search Box when **users do not enter any words and make search**? I don't want any searching process at above case.
2. How can I **exclude Home Page from any search results**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What search results are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the main search result. Let's say we want to search **"Gallery"**. And one of the page also contains **"Gallery"**. We then search from **"Search Bar"** and as a result, we will see all which contain **"Gallery"**. Right? But I don't want that page to appear at Search Result. How can I do this?

Comment: You tagged this as "search". There are a lot of questions in that tag about modifying the search behavior. Does none of that get you started?

Comment: Yes. I found similar questions and tried. I couldn't find them work. Maybe someone can help me by pointing to the similar problems or resources. Thanks @s_ha_dum.

Comment: Ok. So ***what*** did you try?

Comment: [Here is the link!](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85810/exclude-custom-post-type-from-search-by-custom-field-value) I tried to override **pre_get_posts()** method and searching didn't work at all. I'm still finding the solution.

Comment: I asked what _you_ did, exactly, not what someone said to do. Post the code that didn't work.

Comment: Ok. Ok. `add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'modified_pre_get_posts' );
function modified_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'page-home' ) );
    }
    return $query;
}` **"page-home"** is the template name of my home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you tried to use is broken.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'modified_pre_get_posts' ); 
function modified_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $query ) { 
  if ( $query->is_search() ) { 
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'page-home' ) ); 
  } 
  return $query; 
}
```

That function definition is not valid. You would have seen an error if you had [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). You need:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'modified_pre_get_posts' ); 
function modified_pre_get_posts( $query ) { 
  if ( $query->is_search() ) { 
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'page-home' ) ); 
  } 
  return $query; 
}
```

But that will only search ***for*** `post_type` = "page-home". I don't think that is correct either. I assume that is how you'd hoped to exclude the home page. In fact you did something very different. I think you want:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'modified_pre_get_posts' ); 
function modified_pre_get_posts( $query ) { 
  if ( $query->is_search() ) { 
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( id-of-home-page ) ); // should be a number; you have to replace that text with the actual ID
  } 
  return $query; 
}
```

With the default search widget, on my beaten and abused sandbox install, no search runs if I try to submit without any terms. The blog index page loads. If you want to completely interrupt the submission, though, you will need to do it with Javascript.

Comment: Wow! The answer's really perfect! I implemented the function like you said and I got exactly what I want. Thank you so much and really appreciate your help. I'll now try for my first question and I'll post again.